# Get the date in days hours and minute since in django template

Tags: python, django

I want to get date in day hours and minute in django template.

my view.py

```
from django.utils import timezone    
def get_user_specific_android_crave_one(request):

    if request.method=="GET":
        craves1=CraveData.objects.all().count()
        if craves1==0:

            html = render_to_string('crave/ajax/nocrave.html')
            print html
            return HttpResponse(html,mimetype="application/text")
        else:
            craves=list(CraveData.objects.all().order_by("-date"))                
            #fbUser = FacebookUser.objects.get(person=request.user)
            #print fbUser.image                        
            for crave in craves:
                #fbUser = FacebookUser.objects.get(person=CraveData.facebookuser)
                print crave
                nc = timezone.now()
                cc = crave.date
                dc = nc-cc
                secc=dc.seconds
                hours = secc // 3600
                secc = secc - (hours * 3600)
                minutes = secc // 60
                lastc = '%s hours %s minutes ago' % (hours, minutes)
                reply= list(Comment.objects.filter(crave=crave))
                print reply
                for repl in reply:
                crave.reply = reply
                html = render_to_string('crave/ajax/crave.html',{"craves":craves,"lastc":lastc})
                return HttpResponse(html,mimetype="application/json")
```

my crave.html is

```
<div>{% for crave in craves  %}
{{crave.person}}{{ crave }}<br/>
{{lastc}}<!--------- To get date in days hours and minute format since crave made--------->
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here i am getting time but for all crave i am getting same tome like "Two hours 10 minutes ago"  Its same for all crave because i am getting the same variable value from view.
I want to know in template how to convert standered date format of django to date format i want.
I am getting proper date for each crave using {{crave.time}}. But this is standered format by django. I want to display like 1 day ago, 2 hours ago, 20 minutes ago depending on the time crave made.
I searche a lot on net but not got relavent data. please help me out.

Comment: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can user `naturaltime`, here is the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime). A short example:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ datimeobject|naturaltime }}
```

It will display something like `29 seconds ago` or `1 week, 2 days from now`.

Note that you need to **load humanize**

Comment: for this to work we need to add "django.contrib.humanize" in installed app in your application setting.py file.